# Printing the occurrence of mismatch of strings in a list using re.search() in python

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
lst1 = ['abc','xyz']
lst2 = ['abc','xxx']
for i in range(len(lst1)):
    x = re.search(lst2[i], lst1[i])
    print(x)
```

The following code yields an output as follows :

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='abc'>
None
```

This is because 'abc' was found in both lists whereas 'xyz' and 'xxx' conflict.
I am trying to compare the elements in the list and if a mismatch occurs , then i have to print the first occurrence of the mismatch that occurs , is this possible using re.search() ?
something like :

```
Mismatch: lst1
x*yz

lst2
x*xx
```

The first mismatch here has occurred after x in both the lists , hence the desired output.
Please require inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it

```
import re
lst1 = ['abc','xyz']
lst2 = ['abc','xxx']
for i, j in zip(lst1, lst2):
    x = re.search(i, j)
    if x is None:
         first_mismatch = [idx for idx, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(lst1[1], lst2[1])) if a != b][0]
         print('lst1\n{}*{}'.format(i[:idx], i[idx:]))
         print('lst2\n{}*{}'.format(j[:idx], j[idx:]))
```

```
lst1
x*yz
lst2
x*xx
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution ,
While placing a '* ' on the missing string , it gives an error , 
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: Looks like some missing quotes; should probably be `print('lst1\n', i[:first_mismatch], *'', i[first_mismatch:])`

Comment: Will try for all types of input and change the code accordingly. Thank you

Comment: @ManjunathR do you still need help here?

Answer (score 1):

This my solution, you can try it:

```
import re

lst1 = ['abc','xyz','xxzz','xxz']
lst2 = ['abc','xxx','xxx','xxxx']
for i in range( min( len(lst1), len(lst2) )):
    re_compiler=re.compile('^'+lst2[i]+'$')
    match=re_compiler.search(lst1[i])
    if match==None:
        misIndex=0
        for x in range( min( len(lst1[i]), len(lst2[i]) )):
            if lst1[i][x]==lst2[i][x]:
                misIndex+=1
            else: break

        misLst1=(lst1[i][0:misIndex] +'*'+ lst1[i][misIndex:])
        misLst2=(lst2[i][0:misIndex] +'*'+ lst2[i][misIndex:])
        
        print(
            'Mismatch: lst1'+'\n' +
            misLst1 +'\n' +
                    '\n'+
            'lst2'  +'\n' +
            misLst2 +'\n'
            )
```

**output**

```
Mismatch: lst1
x*yz

lst2
x*xx

Mismatch: lst1
xx*zz

lst2
xx*x

Mismatch: lst1
xx*z

lst2
xx*xx
```

Comment: Working well , Will try for other types of input as well. Thank you